# Using Cocoapods libraries in Flutter iOS platform specific code

Tags: ios, swift, flutter, cocoapods, platform-specific

I'm trying to use a Cocoapods library (for an external SDK) but I haven't found any documentation to do it. I've already integrated it in the Android part by just adding a line to the `Gradle` file.

Simply, I would like to create (or maybe find) a `podfile` where I could add my dependency and use it in `AppDelegate.swift` file.

What I tried so far is run `pod init` in `ios/` folder and then add my pod (`pod 'Charts'` for example) and run `pod install` but it says:

> [!] CocoaPods did not set the base configuration of your project because your project already has a custom config set. In order for CocoaPods integration to work at all, please either set the base configurations of the target `Runner` to `Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-Runner/Pods-Runner.release.xcconfig` or include the `Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-Runner/Pods-Runner.release.xcconfig` in your build configuration (`Flutter/Release.xcconfig`).

And then when I try to build on Xcode, it gives me this error:

> error: The sandbox is not in sync with the Podfile.lock. Run 'pod install' or update your CocoaPods installation.

I think I'm doing it the right way and I've found nothing to help me on Flutter.io documentation.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Can you post your Podfile content please?

Comment: I just added some details to specify what i've tried but my problem is that i don't know the correct way to add cocoapods libraries to ios side of Flutter app.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

After you run `pod init` and `pod install` in the `ios/` folder, add

```
#include "Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-Runner/Pods-Runner.debug.xcconfig"
```

to `ios/Flutter/Debug.xcconfig`

and add

```
#include "Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-Runner/Pods-Runner.release.xcconfig"
#include "Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-Runner/Pods-Runner.profile.xcconfig"
```

to `ios/Flutter/Release.xcconfig`

Comment: Thanks ! It's been a while so i already solved the issue but i forgot to add it to my original post ^^'

Comment: In my case, these are automatically added.

Comment: This will get deleted on project clean.

Answer (score 2):

Just put your pods at the end of `Podfile` file which is under the `ios` folder, like:

```
pod 'UMCAnalytics'
```

By default there are some codes in this file but just ignore them and add your pod to below them. After that, run:

```bash
pod update
```

then you will see the pods installed.

Answer (score 0):

Did you add your project target to your `Podfile`? 
Something like that:

```ruby
def swift_frameworks
  pod 'PodName', 'X.X'
end


target 'My Project' do
  swift_frameworks
end
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. However, my problem is that i cannot find any Podfile in the flutter generated app (in ios/ folder for example). Should i create one with `pod init` ? Or there is another way of doing it ?